# Duplicating debug configuration for multi Scheme is not working in React native-iOS

Tags: react-native-ios, xcode-scheme, xcode-build-settings

I've developed my project using react native, and now I am trying to implement multi-scheme for my dev, uat, and prod environments.

For the above, I've setup schemes and duplicated the release and debug configuration for each one of the scheme, and specified the different bundle ids, different app names, user defined variables. Now my situation is if I am running the scheme locally( as for run the debug configuration is set) then I'm falling into the below error:

Thread 6: "Unhandled JS Exception: Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'DevSettings' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the na..., stack:\ngetEnforcing@4725:28\n@41349:50\nloadModuleImplementation@271:14\n@41308:40\nloadModuleImplementation@271:14\n@35877:18\nloadModuleImplementation@271:14\n@28987:16\nloadModuleImplementation@271:14\nguardedLoadModule@163:47\nglobal code@326655:4\n"

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RCTFatalException: Unhandled JS Exception: Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'DevSettings' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary.', reason: 'Unhandled JS Exception: Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'DevSettings' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the na..., stack:

*** I've attached screenshot of my Development scheme setting where I've used release build config(Development) and debug build config(DevelopmentDebug)

[Check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dbXG.png)

FYI:

If I choose release build configuration for Run, Test and Analyse and run the scheme then it is working fine, but in this case I can't use debugger for my development purpose.

Also, I don't have any issues with archiving or releasing the archive to testflight using CICD, as I've selected the release configuration for Archive and Profile under the scheme setting.

Please help me out, as this will make the development very difficult, as I don't have access to the debugger window.

Looking forward to get positive help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

(: Please try to add some logs that would be very helpful

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RCTFatalException: Unhandled JS Exception: Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'DevSettings' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary.', reason: 'Unhandled JS Exception: Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'DevSettings' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the na..., stack:

Comment: I'm facing the same issue and found this link https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28738 which has more findings, it seems like React native bundle is more of deals only with Debug config, once we create a duplicate of Debug and name it like DebugQA or DebugUat, it seems like doesn't work  in simulator with any other name except Debug. This is frustrating that i couldn't able to debug my code for other schemes except default Debug.